# create uiimagepicker with tumbnail button to library

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I just stumbled upon the whatsapp interface for taking a picture. They seem to use a native control like `UIImagePickerController` but customized it by adding a thumbnail button to the image library:

[image]

I found that rather interesting and tried to make something similiar but I couldn't find a way to even display a tumbnail of the `UIImagePicker library`

I'm hoping some on here knows.

Answer (score 0):

You've to user `UIImagePickerController` or `AVCaptureSession` to create your customize camera (a camera with a custom overlay view).

Here's Apple's example for each,

[UIImagePickerController with custom overlay example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Listings/PhotoPicker_APLViewController_m.html) - Easy to implement

[AVCaptureSession with custom overlay example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html) - Little tough but best approach

Also, this is just a start, there's lots of example available, you only need to google it. All the best!

Comment: I'm especially interested in the usage of UIImagePickerController in this use case, as this screen capture has almost all controls exactly the same, except for the library tumbnail/button. This would indicate some sort of customization while tapping into some styling that apple provided.

Comment: @bdv, OK, but if you want some customization then you've to add your own camera overlay view for this. See the source code I provided in my answer. That's from Apple it self. If you find my answer useful please give an +1 (up vote) and mark it as correct answer.

Comment: I understand that, the nuance in my question is in the fact that the custom overlay seems to be made with components already provided by apple, and I want to know how to achieve just that (the capture image, the battery image, etc)

Comment: If you're using `UIImagePickerController` without custom overlay view, then you'll get the default camera without gallery option but all the features which have the default camera app. But if you want to make it customize then you've to add a view on `UIImagePickerController` inside `cameraOverlayView` and also needs to add `UIButton`s (or something which can handle actions) for flash, swap camera, capture a photo etc. features of a camera. This isn't a hurdle but time taken. You can do it with apple's sample and lots of other examples available.